# Kivy object doesn't render when defined in .kv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, python-2.x, kivy-language

I'm developing an app in kivy and currently trying to figure out why I can get an object to render when I add it in Python but not in the .kv file.

This works fine, rendering the background image with a switch on top of it.

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.layout.add_widget(defSwitch())
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.parent.current = 'data'

class defSwitch(Switch):
    active = False
```

Where the .kv file is:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    imgname: './images/' + 'login.jpg'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.imgname
```

This doesn't render anything but the background image:

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.parent.current = 'data'

class defSwitch(Switch):
    active = False
```

where in this case the .kv file has:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    imgname: './images/' + 'login.jpg'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.imgname
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        defSwitch:
```

If I replace defSwitch: in the .kv file by a default Switch object, then it renders fine.  Why can't I use a custom object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a custom class created in `.py` file with kv language, you need to set it in `.kv` file too:

```
<defScreen>:    # class def

<LoginScreen>:
    ...
    defScreen:  # object
```

so that it knows what to look for.

Also I'd like to recommend you using camel case in kv language as there are [situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40030291/5994041) in which the parser won't recognize the phrase as a widget.