# Kivy throws an unexpected 'syntax error' only for the first instance of a dynamic class

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm attempting to use a [Dynamic Class](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes) to make all Text Inputs in my Kivy app go through the same validation callback. Here's the sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<smRoot>:
    SignUpScreen:
<signupText@TextInput>:
    font_size: '15sp'
    on_text_validate: app.callback1()
    multiline: False

<SignUpScreen>:
    font_size:'50sp'
    name:'signupscreen'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.09,0.65,0.8)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.75, .5)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'
        signupText:
            hint_text: 'Full Name'
        signupText:
            hint_text: 'Mobile Number'
        signupText:
            hint_text: 'Enter Password'
        signupText:
            hint_text: 'Re-Enter Password'
        Button:
            text: 'Sign Up'
            disabled: True
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)
class smRoot(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    pass

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        smroot = smRoot()
        return smroot

    def callback1(self):
        print 'In Validation Callback'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user/Workspace1/ScratchArea/Scratch.py", line 39, in <module>
     Builder.load_string(kv)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1491, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1049, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1126, in parse
     rule.precompile()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 917, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 913, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 843, in precompile
     self.co_value = compile(value, self.ctx.filename or '<string>', mode)
   File "<string>", line 29
     hint_text: 'Re-Enter Password'
              ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Surprisingly though, when I change **only the first** instance of the `signupText` class to the parent `TextInput` it works:

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint: (.75, .5)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        hint_text: 'Full Name'
    signupText:
        hint_text: 'Mobile Number'
    signupText:
        hint_text: 'Enter Password'
    signupText:
        hint_text: 'Re-Enter Password'
    Button:
        text: 'Sign Up'
        disabled: True
```

With this small change, the syntax error is no longer thrown. But in this case, of course, the callback only works on the last three TextInput boxes...!

Is it that Kivy somehow requires the parent class to be instantiated once before dynamic classes can inherit from it? Or is there some error in my code? Any help/pointers/suggestions in this regard would be appreciated...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kv language widget names must start with an uppercase letter.

You must name `signupText` as `SignupText`. See [How to duplicate blocks of widgets in kv file (lowercase-only rule)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027001/how-to-duplicate-blocks-of-widgets-in-kv-file-lowercase-only-rule)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<SmRoot>:
    SignUpScreen:
<SignupText@TextInput>:
    font_size: '15sp'
    on_text_validate: app.callback1()
    multiline: False

<SignUpScreen>:
    font_size:'50sp'
    name:'signupscreen'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.09,0.65,0.8)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.75, .5)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'
        SignupText:
            hint_text: 'Full Name'
        SignupText:
            hint_text: 'Mobile Number'
        SignupText:
            hint_text: 'Enter Password'
        SignupText:
            hint_text: 'Re-Enter Password'
        Button:
            text: 'Sign Up'
            disabled: True
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)
class smRoot(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    pass

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        smroot = smRoot()
        return smroot

    def callback1(self):
        print('In Validation Callback')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()





    Builder.load_string(kv)
    class SmRoot(ScreenManager):
        pass

    class SignUpScreen(Screen):
        pass

    class myApp(App):
        def build(self):
            smroot = SmRoot()
            return smroot

        def callback1(self):
            print('In Validation Callback')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        myApp().run()
```

Comment: I bought two books, which both at some early stage introduce Dynamic Classes, and both books fail to mention that vital rule. And the syntax error points to the wrong line!